# Deselecting an array in mongoose in schema definition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

Basically what the title says. I have this inside a Schema:

```
meta: [{
    event: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event', required: true, unique: true},
    views: {type: Number, default: 0},
    clicks: {type: Number, default: 0}
}]
```

I want to define by default to mongoose to not select that field.
Something like:

```
otherField: {type: String, select: false}
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
meta: {
    type: [{
        event: {type:  Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event', required: true, unique: true},
        views: {type: Number, default: 0},
        clicks: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }],
    select: false
}
```

Is it even possible to deselect **complex** arrays on schema creation?
I know for certain this does work:

```
meta: {type: Array, select: false}
```

but that way the schema isn't properly defined.

Comment: I tried the code that you say: "I've tried this but it didn't work", and it excluded `meta` from any `find` output by default just fine. This is with Mongoose 4.4.14.

Comment: maybe, but try adding items to the list, that did not work.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you're using to add items to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to create a new sub schema

```
var metaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    event: {type:  Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event', required: true, unique: true},
    views: {type: Number, default: 0},
    clicks: {type: Number, default: 0}
});
```

and use it with select:false

```
    meta: {type: [metaSchema], select: false}
```